# Entity Framework 4.1: Using TPH and mapping properties to existing database columns

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, code-first, entity-framework-4.1

I got this simple class hierarchy;

```
public class A 
{  
 [Key]
 public int Id { get; set; }
}  

public class B : A 
{
 public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class C : A 
{
 public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Using TPH this will end upp with a table looking something like this;

> Table A, fields Id, Name, Name1, Discriminator.

I want class B and C name property to map to the same field, ie Name, using these mappings.

```
Property(x => x.Id)
  .HasColumnName("Id");

Map<B>(m =>
{
    m.Properties(p => new
    {
        Name = p.Name,
    });
});

Map<C>(m =>
{
    m.Properties(p => new
    {
        Name = p.Name,
    });
});
```

How can I make sure to map to the same column for my subtypes (B and C) property Name? Is there a HasColumnName to be used with the Properties collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

THP does not allow for you to share properties between the objects unless the property is on the base class. Using TPH, a property is either Shared between all implementations or belongs to one of the specialized implementations.

Place Name property on the base class and this should solve your problem.

Comment: This might be troublesome since my real problem involves more subclasses with different properties... But I anyway realize I have to go the TPT way for meeting my demands in the best way.